# Calling function C#

Tags: c#, function

How would I call this function

```
    public void AdvertisingBot(Player player, PlayerTextPacket packet)
    {
        string name = "Bot";
        var plr = player.Manager.FindPlayer(name);

        if (packet.Text.Contains("servernameexample"))
        {
            plr.Manager.Chat.Say(plr, "Please do not avertise, I'm watching..");
        }
    }
```

doesnt really matter what the code does i dont think but if you have to know, it just looks for the player in-game named Bot and when a player says whats in the quote, the Bot will send a message saying no advertising.

Comment: What does "How would I call this function" mean? You would call the function using an instance of Player and an instance of PlayerTextPacket, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that function belonged to a class named `ClassA` then this would be how you'd do it:

```
var c = new ClassA();
c.AdvertisingBot( player, packet);
```

Obviously you'd need an instance for that types represented by the variables `player` and `packet.`  Your question is lacking detail...